# Regex for VS Find and replace - empty else blocks

Tags: c#, regex, visual-studio-2010

We have recently replaced a bunch of code in our solution leaving us with a lot of empty else statements. I'd like to do a find and replace all using a regex string and was wondering if anyone could produce a Regex to use in VS2010's find and replace to find all patterns matching the code below:

```
 else
            {}
```

I've tried to modify some of the patterns i've found in other questions relating to empty catch blocks on stackoverflow to no avail.

Thanks!

Comment: Use Resharper and do a code cleanup :)

Comment: Is it just else blocks that you are looking for? or empty blocks in general

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
else[\n:b]*\{[\n:b]*\}
```

this says look for else, followed by any white space or line breaks, then { followed by any white space or line breaks then }

Matches any of the following:

```
else{}    //No breaks
else {  } //Space in between
else{     //Single line break
}
else      //Muliple line breaks
{

}
```